# how to wait before the perform "click called" in main activity?

Tags: android

```
package com.continuesvoicerecognition;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView result_tv;
    private Button start_listen_btn,stop_listen_btn,mute;
    private SpeechRecognizerManager mSpeechManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViews();
        setClickListeners();
        foo();
    }




    private void findViews()
    {
        result_tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_tv);
        start_listen_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start_listen_btn);
        stop_listen_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_listen_btn);
        mute=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mute);
    }
    private void foo()
    {

        start_listen_btn.performClick();

    }


    private void setClickListeners()
    {
        start_listen_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop_listen_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mute.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(PermissionHandler.checkPermission(this,PermissionHandler.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.start_listen_btn:
                    if(mSpeechManager==null)
                    {
                        SetSpeechListener();
                    }
                    else if(!mSpeechManager.ismIsListening())
                    {
                        mSpeechManager.destroy();
                        SetSpeechListener();
                    }
                    result_tv.setText(getString(R.string.you_may_speak));

                    break;
                case R.id.stop_listen_btn:
                    if(mSpeechManager!=null) {
                        result_tv.setText(getString(R.string.destroied));
                        mSpeechManager.destroy();
                        mSpeechManager = null;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.mute:
                    if(mSpeechManager!=null) {
                        if(mSpeechManager.isInMuteMode()) {
                            mute.setText(getString(R.string.mute));
                            mSpeechManager.mute(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mute.setText(getString(R.string.un_mute));
                            mSpeechManager.mute(true);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PermissionHandler.askForPermission(PermissionHandler.RECORD_AUDIO,this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case PermissionHandler.RECORD_AUDIO:
                if(grantResults.length>0) {
                    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        start_listen_btn.performClick();
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    private void SetSpeechListener()
    {
        mSpeechManager=new SpeechRecognizerManager(this, new SpeechRecognizerManager.onResultsReady() {
            @Override
            public void onResults(ArrayList<String> results) {



                if(results!=null && results.size()>0)
                {

                    if(results.size()==1)
                    {
                        mSpeechManager.destroy();
                        mSpeechManager = null;
                        result_tv.setText("");
                        result_tv.setText(results.get(0));
                    }
                    else {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        if (results.size() > 5) {
                            results = (ArrayList<String>) results.subList(0, 5);
                        }
                        for (String result : results) {
                            sb.append(result).append("\n");
                        }
                        result_tv.setText("");
                        result_tv.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
                else
                    result_tv.setText(getString(R.string.no_results_found));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(mSpeechManager!=null) {
            mSpeechManager.destroy();
            mSpeechManager=null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

here is the code. i have to make a voice recognition app that
automatically call the function to perform the action. for this
purpose i have to call "perform click" after 5 second and after
completing the perform click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void repeatAbleTask() {
        final long waitInterval = 5000L;
        myDefaultView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repeatAbleTask()
            }
        }, waitInterval);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
final long changeTime = 5000L;
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call your function here
    }
}, changeTime);
```

Comment: Not solving my problem...... i just want that the function should call after 5 second..and After completing the function time it should again wait for 5 seconds.